# Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] - Angularjs (1.8.3)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What am I doing wrong?
I try write simple example with use book, but I get error.
What needs to be fixed in this example to make it work?

what else write there?

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>page 29</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script 
            type="text/javascript" 
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.3/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script> 
        var Ctrl = function ($scope) {
            $scope.getName = function() {
                return $scope.name
            }
        }
    </script>

    <body ng-app>
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            Напиши свои мысли о ангуляре
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <h1> angularjs - {{getName()}} </h1> 
            <p> 

            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```

In console I watch error:

```
    Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] 
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.3/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=Ctrl
    at angular.js:99:1
    at angular.js:11787:17
    at ea (angular.js:10818:34)
    at p (angular.js:10603:32)
    at g (angular.js:9942:13)
    at g (angular.js:9945:13)
    at angular.js:9807:30
    at angular.js:1968:11
    at m.$eval (angular.js:19523:16)
    at m.$apply (angular.js:19622:20)
```

Comment: " I try write simple example with use book," You might want to describe what you are trying to do instead.

Comment: i try write code which will be work

Comment: And wrote. It is can see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - First example:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>page 29</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script 
            type="text/javascript" 
            src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.8.3/angular.min.js">
    </script>
    <script> 
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);
        myApp.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        //var Ctrl = function ($scope) {
            $scope.getName = function() {
                return $scope.name
            }
        }]
        )
        
    </script>

    <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
            Напиши свои мысли о ангуляре
            <input type="text" ng-model="name">
            <h1> angularjs - {{getName()}} </h1> 
            <p> 

            </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</head>
</html>
```